# VS Diagnostic Tools & Globally-Scoped Unique Pointers

Tags: c++, memory, visual-studio-2019, unique-ptr, diagnostic-tools

I have been looking at the following piece of code:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

unique_ptr<int> uptr;

int main()
{
    uptr = make_unique<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

I used two tools to test it: Valgrind (running on WSL with Ubuntu) and Visual Studio's Memory Usage diagnostic tool. (The purpose was to see how the latter works, already having some (limited) practical experience with Valgrind.) The intention was to make sure that the globally-scoped unique pointer gets released as I expect it to.

Valgrind reports no leaks, errors, or warnings of any kind – indeed, as expected.
As for the Microsoft tool: I set one breakpoint in the opening curly bracket, and one in the ending curly bracket; I then take a snapshot at each. The breakpoint at the second curly bracket is reached *after* the execution of the return statement. The result of this is bamboozling: there is one more allocation documented in the second snapshot when compared to the first, and that allocation *is* that of the integer pointed at by `uptr` from my code.
I had also attempted to walk step-by-step with F11 (Step Into) into the post-`main()` parts of the code, all the way to the `exit` call that terminates the program (tried stepping into that one too but F11 just caused the end of execution), and take snapshots at each step: that leftover allocation remains in each of them.
I had lastly attempted to add the following line right before `return 0;`:

```
delete uptr.release();
```

This made no difference on the Valgrind front (still no leaks/errors/warnings), but solved the extra allocation "issue" (maybe just a misunderstanding on my part) on the VS front.

Now to my actual question:
Why is this happening? Is this actually an issue, or am I just misunderstanding something?
To rephrase: does this extra allocation (I'll add a picture below to demonstrate) imply unreleased dynamically-allocated memory, of the kind that would occur if I used `new` without `delete`ing? And if so, then is it because of something I did wrong?

Depicted here are the diagnostic tool snapshots:
[image: Snapshots]
And clicking on the "+1" to reveal more information shows that it is indeed the integer allocated within the `make_unique` call.

Comment: The `uptr` is a global variable. When it's assigned is regardless. It will release its contents latest in its own destructor. Hence, this should happen _after_ return of `main()` i.e. in the wrapper code which is added by the compiler to do things before and after `main()` where allocation of globals (before) and the corresponding destruction (after) belong to.

Comment: Have you tried to step *into* the `exit` call, all the way to the actual process termination?

Comment: O.T.: `delete uptr.release()`? Why not [uptr.reset()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset)? ;-)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude – yeah, I tried to step as deeply as VS would let me: F11 on the `exit` call just resulted in the end of execution. Makes sense that it happens there, though!

Comment: @Scheff'sCat – I'm a hipster! :-)  
(Serious response: I'm inexperienced with smart pointers, and was familiar off-the-top-of-my-head with `release()` but not with `reset()`; I also just wanted to run a quick test and therefore didn't think to Google for the right way to do this. Thanks for this comment, noted for the future!)

Comment: Concerning the globals... Usually, I try to prevent them but sometimes they appear the most justified way to manage something which is really global and unique in the application. As such globals  usually are intended to live at least until return from `main()`, the concern about memory leaks is the lesser issue. (Any common desktop OS reclaims any process memory as free after exit of process.) Of course, there are exceptions: e.g. shared memory or resource management which relies on the proper execution of the destructors.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you :) In that case, I'm guessing the memory's reclaimed at some point beyond those that VS supports grabbing a snapshot of.